# Show my activity instead of standard screen for outgoing call

Tags: android, call

I'm developing an application for android 2.3.3. It contains a few TextViews to show an information for outgoing call: country, current time, phone number... The problem I faced is that I don't know how to show my activity instead of the standard screen for outgoing calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [System Overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android) in android. It can be used to put a custom window on top of the call screen.

Comment: thanks, can i make a call without showing UI, means user can talk to other person while using my application.